# using python turtle to display values on a gauge

Tags: python

I have a geiger counter connected to an arduino.
The sketch spits out the sievert value which is a two decimals float.
I am trying to display the value on a circular dial.

It is most obviously a pebkac, but I am a bit stuck on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./turtle-gauge.py", line 60, in <module> draw_gauge(sev, pen)
  File "./turtle-gauge.py", line 53, in draw_gauge
    angle = int((sev / 40) * 360)
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Here is the code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import turtle
import serial
import time

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.title("Geiger Counter")
wn.tracer(0)

# Let there be a serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1')
ser.flushInput()

# Let there be a functon to read it
def read_sev():
    sev = ser.readline()
    sev = float(sev[0:len(sev)-5].decode("utf-8"))

# Let there be a drawing tool
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(3)

# Let there be a gauge with a hand
def draw_gauge(sev, pen):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(0,210)
    pen.setheading(180)
    pen.color("green")
    pen.pendown()
    pen.circle(210)
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0,0)
    pen.setheading(90)

    for _ in range(40):
        pen.fd(190)
        pen.pendown()
        pen.fd(20)
        pen.penup()
        pen.goto(0,0)
        pen.rt(50)
    # Draw the gauge hand
    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(0,0)
    pen.color("white")
    pen.setheading(90)
    angle = (sev / 40) * 360
    pen.rt(angle)
    pen.pendown()
    pen.fd(200)

while True:
    sev=read_sev()
    draw_gauge(sev, pen)
    wn.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    pen.clear()

wn.mainloop()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sev=read_sev()`, the function `read_sev()` must return a value. If you don't return a value, it will give you `None`.

The error occurs because sev is `None`, and you can't divide `None` by 40.

To fix the error, you simply have to `return sev` in your `read_sev()` function.